# Custom Document ID Provider Stops Assigning Values

Tags: 2010, custom, document-id

We wrote a custom document ID provider to assign friendly number (1,2,3,etc.) to documents scoped at the farm level. All site collections use this provider, so no matter where the document is saved - it will receive the next number available. The values are tracked in a SQL database.

My problem is that the custom provider occasionally stops working. Both the DocID service and my custom provider are activated, but for some reason it will stop using my custom provider and revert to the default DocID like PX839912ASS. The fix is simply deactivating my custom provider, and then turning it back on.

Unfortunately this is really annoying, and I'm having a tough time figuring out why this is happening. It seems completely random at this point. Has anyone seen this behavior with custom providers?

Comment: Are there any details in your ULS logs or in the server Event Logs?

Comment: Well I've spent a lot of time researching, and I really still can't figure out what happened. I basically went to each site collection and made sure to disable/enable the feature, and then test that new documents were getting the proper value. I haven't seen the issue since originally reporting it. I'm wondering if for some reason a timer job was stalling and not assigned the value in real time, so when I was doing my spot checks it just appeared to not be working. Kind of a ridiculous thing to assume, but I just can't figure out how it happened. Thanks anyways!